# How to arrange controls side-by-side without using TableLayoutPanel?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have been using `TableLayoutPanel` for arranging controls. Recently I discovered that `TableLayoutPanel` does not support visual inheritance. I am now in the process of removing `TableLayoutPanel` from my project. However, I do not understand how to arrange controls side-by-side. So far, what I see is that I can set the `Dock` property of controls to either '`Top`' or '`Bottom`' and they will stack on top of each other in the order they are added to the `Form.Controls` collection. The problem with this is that I would like to have the controls side-by-side (horizontally) instead of being on top of each other (vertically). Note that I want to use the `Dock` property so that controls resize automatically when the Form is resized by the user. I do not want static controls that cannot resize.

I do want a solution that supports visual inheritance. There are a number of controls that do not support this, as explained here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1z3efhd2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: `TableLayoutPanel` doesn't support inheritance, but controls that are in them do. It is possible to have table layout and inheritance, but depending on what you actually want to achieve it may need more work to glue it all together.

Comment: The only thing you really can't do is change things in the designer. In code all properties are accessible; you can set its Dock mode, add controls etc.. So if you want to use the designer for layout, I guess you really have to give up on TLPs. - As for using Dock: I don't think it works well for multiple controls. I guess you'll have to write a layout function called in the Form resize.

Comment: You can make your life a lot easier by adding a few panels to group some controls and Anchor them in there.. - As for layout-side-by-side: You will have to __precisely define__ the resizing behaviour (for each control)  you want as there are many ways to do it. Some should other shouldn't grow etc..